# App Engine nested entity list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In google cloud datastore I have code equivalent to this:

```
req = datastore.CommitRequest()
req.mode = datastore.CommitRequest.NON_TRANSACTIONAL
foo = req.mutation.insert_auto_id.add()

barListProperty = foo.property.add()
barListValue = []
for i in range(5):
    ent = datastore.Entity()
    a = ent.property.add()
    set_property(a, 'a', 1)
    b = ent.property.add()
    set_property(b, 'b', i)

set_property(barListProperty, 'barlist', barListValue)

key = datastore.Key()
path_element = key.path_element.add()
path_element.kind = 'Foo'

foo.key.CopyFrom(key)
print datastore.commit(req)
```

Now I wanted to build the same thing in NDB so I wrote this:

```
class Foo(Expando):
    pass

foo = Foo()
foo.barlist = [Expando(a=1, b=i) for i in range(5)]
foo.put()
```

But I get the following error:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~detect-analyze-notify-01a/sjuul.373145649709860280/main.py", line 317, in get
    foo.put()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3339, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 748, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 280, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 454, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1818, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1333, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: BLOB, ENITY_PROTO or TEXT properties must be in a raw_property field.
```

How should I go about this?

EDIT: This didn't work either

```
    class Foo(Expando):
        pass

    class Bar(Expando):
        pass

    foo = Foo()
    foo.barlist=[Bar(a=1, b=i) for i in range(5)]
    foo.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the Expando model directly. You will need to create a subclass of ndb.Expando for the repeated property for this to work.

e.g.

```
s~lightning-catfish> class X(ndb.Expando):
...    pass

s~lightning-catfish> class Repeated(ndb.Expando):
...    pass
... 
s~lightning-catfish> z = X()
s~lightning-catfish> z.y = [Repeated(a=1,b=i) for i in range(5)]
s~lightning-catfish> z.y
[Repeated(a=1, b=0), Repeated(a=1, b=1), Repeated(a=1, b=2), Repeated(a=1, b=3), Repeated(a=1, b=4)]
```

Comment: Did you try saving to the datastore? I get the same exception. See the edit of my post for the code that I've used. Note btw that the exception gets raised at `foo.put()`

Comment: Yep you are correct.  I have just been reading the source of Expando class and I don't believe you can do what you want with it at the moment.  Currently if the property is of Model (ie Structured) it creates an StructuredProperty, if it's a list it wraps it in a GenericProperty, but nesting an Expando doesn't seem to be handled.  You can  repeat an Expando in a StructuredProperty though.

Comment: See an example of it in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631884/ndb-querying-a-genericproperty-in-repeated-expando-structuredproperty

Comment: If you repost your comment as answer I'll accept it as the correct answer. It's a shame that this is not possible in AE. I'm rewriting my existing code base so that AE can also read/write those entities.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand well: does all your discussion means that nesting an Expando (or list of Expandos) inside another Expando is currently not supported? I have the following problem and it could ex plain the integrity errors I'm facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185690/custom-properties-not-saved-correctly-for-expando-models-in-repeated-structuredp. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct, the current ndb code base makes this impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you're trying to save an entity that itself wasn't persisted yet, which leaves a couple of options:

1) If you want to have the `Entity` stored as a separate "row", you can save it, and then store a list of keys:

```
class Entity(db.Expando):
  pass

# Create your main entity.
e = Entity()
e.other_entities = []

# Create a bunch of others.
for i in range(5):
  other_entity = Entity(a=i, b=i+1)
  other_entity.put()
  # Attach the key to the main entity.
  e.other_entities.append(other_entity.key())

# Save your main entity.
e.put()
```

2) If you want the `Entity` stored "in-line" you might be able to use the [`db.EmbeddedEntity` type](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py#1213):

```
class Entity(db.Expando):
  pass

# Create your main entity.
e = Entity()
e.other_entities = []

# Create a bunch of others (but don't save them).
for i in range(5):
  other_entity = Entity(a=i, b=i+1)
  # Append it to the list as an EmbeddedEntity
  e.other_entities.append(db.EmbeddedEntity(other_entity))

# Save your main entity.
e.put()
```

An example sort of like this is on [the main Expando documentation page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass), where they use `db.Text('Text value')` to specify that it should be stored as a `TextProperty` and not a `StringProperty`.

Comment: Does that de-serialise back to a `datastore.Entity` class in google cloud datastore? My main goal is to have both codebases to work in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to set a new entity for the list. SO you can insert as many items as you may need, as instances of the 'list entity', and you can set the other entity as it parent.

Instead of this (or similar):

```
foo = Foo()
foo.barlist=[Bar(a=1, b=i) for i in range(5)]
foo.put()
```

you could try this:

```
foo = ListFoo(parent= Foo)
foo.item = 'list item'
foo.put()
```