# Custom properties not saved correctly for Expando models in repeated StructuredProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to use an `Expando` model as a repeated `StructuredProperty` in another model. Namely, I would like to add an indefinite number of `Accounts` to my `User` model. As `Accounts` can have different properties depending on their types (`Accounts` are references to social network accounts, and for example Twitter requires more information than Facebook for its OAuth process), I have designed my `Account` model as an `Expando`. I've added all basic information in the model definition, but I plan to add custom properties for specific social networks (e.g., a specific `access_token_secret` property for Twitter).

1/ Can you confirm the following design (`Expando` in repeated `StructuredProperty`) *should* work?

```
class Account(ndb.Expando):
    account_type = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, choices=['fb', 'tw', 'li'])
    account_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    state = ndb.StringProperty()
    access_token = ndb.StringProperty()

class HUser(User):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, validator=validate_email)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    accounts = ndb.StructuredProperty(Account, repeated=True)
```

2/ Now the problem I am facing is: when I add a Facebook account to my `HUser` instance, everything works fine ; however the problem rises when I append a Twitter account to that same instance, and add a new property not declared in the model, like that:

```
for account in huser.accounts:
    if account.state == "state_we_re_looking_for" and account.account_type == 'tw':
        # we found the appropriate Twitter account reference
        account.access_token_secret = "..." # store the access token secret fetched from Twitter API
        huser.put() # save to the Datastore
        break
```

This operation is supposed to save the access token secret in the Twitter `Account` instance of my `User`, but in fact it saves it in the *Facebook* `Account` instance (at index 0)!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental problem with how ndb stores the `StructuredProperty`. Datastore does not currently have a way to store this, so ndb basically explodes your properties.

For example, consider the entity:

```
HUser(email='test@example.com'.
      accounts=(Account(type='fb',
                        account_id='1',
                        state='1',
                        access_token='1'),
                Account(type='tw',
                        account_id='2',
                        state='2',
                        access_token='2',
                        access_token_secret='2')))
```

This will actually get stored in an entity that looks like:

```
{
 email : 'test@example.com',
 accounts.type : ['fb', 'tw'],
 accounts.account_id : ['1', '2'],
 accounts.state : ['1', '2'],
 accounts.access_token : ['1', '2'],
 accounts.access_token_secret : ['2']
}
```

Because you are using an `ndb.Expando`, ndb doesn't know that it should populate the `access_token_secret` field with a `None` for the facebook account. When ndb repopulates your entities, it will fill in the `access_token_secret` for the first account it sees, which is the facebook account.

Restructuring your data sounds like the right way to go about this, but you may want to make your HUser an ancestor of the `Account` for that `HUser` so that you query for a user's accounts using [strong consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: Wow... I was thinking of electing my own answer as the right one, but yours is much more detailed, thank you! As for your last suggestion, I will look into it, but I have one question: if I create `Account` entities with an ancestor reference to the corresponding `HUser`, what should my `Account` model become? I guess I can safely remove the `KeyProperty` I was talking about in my answer, but should I declare anything about the ancestor? If not, then it means the ancestor won't be mandatory and I might forget to set one in the future?

Comment: There isn't really any way to declare an ancestor rather than setting it when you create the Account. You're right that this may be more prone to error (since you can't mark it as mandatory). However at this point you should be accessing all Accounts for a user with a query like: `Account.query(ancestor=huser.key)`. So if you forget to set the ancestor, you should notice that this new type of account doesn't show up. More importantly, this is strongly consistent, so you are guaranteed that you'll always get all the accounts for a user.

Comment: Another thought -- you can always add a method to your `HUser` model that adds an account. At the very least, `Account`s will always get created in the context of the `HUser`. Something like this https://github.com/proppy/appengine-todos-flask/commit/ef582ccfe7f468604e4dad0ab563f896268aaad9#diff-fafd174e32950faa08cce18610c43170R74 (sorry for the link to in-progress code).

Comment: Thank you very much for these details, I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it seems like App Engine NDB does not support `Expando` entities containing `Expando` entities themselves.

One thing that I didn't realize at first is that my `HUser` model inherits from Google's `User` class, which is precisely an `Expando` model!

So without even knowing it, I was trying to put a repeated `StructuredProperty` of `Expando` objects inside another `Expando`, which seemingly *is not* supported (I didn't find anything clearly written on this limitation, however).

The solution is to design the data model in a different way. I put my `Account` objects in a separate entity kind (and this time, they are truly `Expando` objects!), and I've added a `KeyProperty` to reference the `HUser` entity. This involves more read/write ops, but the code is actually much simpler to read now...

I'll mark my own question as answered, unless someone has another interesting input regarding the limitation found here.

Comment: I think it is mentioned. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=nl#structured .

If I am correct and understand your case correctly

Comment: Are you referring to the yellow paragraph? It does say that you cannot nest repeated `StructuredProperty` in another repeated `StructuredProperty`, but nothing is said about `Expando` models. Or I'm blind? :)

Comment: Sorry might be my mistake for the reference. Will try to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, but no need to reproduce it: look at @Patrick Costello's detailed explanation.